# visual studio 2010 for windows phone

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

please any one help me to develop windows phone app in m windows 7 ultimate operating system.
please I have tried more than three days but not succeeded.
I am having vs 2010,2008 also.
please i think visual studio 2010 for windows phone software is needed.
I have searched long time for this also.
please help me guys.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why Visual Studio 2010? You can download Visual Studio Express 2013 for free. It's all you need to develop Windows Phone apps.

[Download Express 2013 for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

Comment: AFAIK Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows phone is only available for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have download windows phone 7 sdk from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27570) link.. It's working fine.

And also try this links

[Link 1](https://archive.org/details/WindowsPhoneSDK71_iso)

[Link 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2011/09/28/10217841.aspx)

[Link 3](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=WPSDKv71_en1&oq=WPSDKv71_en1&aqs=chrome..69i57.543j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=WPSDKv71_en1)